# Textpipe: extracting text between two tags

Tags: html, text, tags, extract

I can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this task with **TextPipe**.

**TASK:**

Extract (cut out) this TEXT *including* the start and end tag and get a file containing only these tags and the text in between.

```
<div><div class="article">`TEXT`<span id="contentBottomLeft"></span>
```

I defined a restriction filter with an end and start tag, but what's next? This filter demands a subfilter and I don't understand what exact filter I need to use next and how to customize it. I need to repeat this extraction process for several thousands of HTML files.

Steps specifically for **TextPipe** will be greatly appreaciated, as I'm not much a of a programmer myself.

Comment: Well, 'thanks' for that non-answer. I know HTML, but this is how it appears in the original HTML file, and besides I need some unique identifiers to extract that particular piece of text.

Comment: Are you saying the file is already imbalanced, and you need to remove two spurious <div> opening tags?

Comment: I'm saying I don't see how it's relevant in the first place; this is an operation to be performed on a series of mass-downloaded HTML files as they come, and is this happens to be the unique starting point for the piece of text in the HTML files that I need. In order to make sure of that, I included the tags "as is". For my purporses the double div don't matter. All I need to do is remove all text before the first tag and after the last one, thereby keeping the string above with the unique text in the middle.

Comment: Aaah! So by "Extract (cut out)" you mean that you want to *keep only* the text and tags that appear in that context?

Comment: Exaactly:) And then run the script on a thousand other files.

Comment: You should consider marking Simon's answer as the accepted answer as his answer directly relates to TextPipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any further help from yourself, I can only guess that you want to remove all <div> elements whose first child is another <div> element with a class attribute equal to "article".

After a quick look at the [TextPipe documentation](http://www.datamystic.com/textpipe/htmlhelp/replace%20menu/find_html.htm) it looks like it won't do anything like XPath expressions, but you should experiment with a `Restrict to between tags` filter and a `Remove All` subfilter.

Bear in mind that it is possible that TextPipe won't do what you want and you may have to look elsewhere for a solution.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your input. I'm sure, though, that TextPipe can do it, the way of doing it just confuses me, as the program evolves around filters and subfilters, and I'm not quite sure which one of them to employ AFTER the restriction filter. Besides, I think you read way too much into this, this task only involves cutting out a specific chunk with a preset starting and end point. The purpose is further post-processing of the resulting text with regex.

Comment: Riight, so I'll briefly clarify the solution to this task for others to benefit of it also.

In the "Find" field, define a Perl-pattern:

`<div><div class="article">(.*?)<span id="contentBottomLeft">`

and choose "Send non-matching text to subfilter"

Then create a "Remove All" subfilter to the Perl-pattern. That will yield a text file with *only* this (and no other text surrounding it):

`<TAG1>`
Text
`<TAG2>`

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty easy with TextPipe, which BTW is awesome.

Add a perl search and replace pattern filter, with search text of:

```
<div><div class="article">[^<]*<span id="contentBottomLeft"></span>
```

- here, TEXT can be any characters except a '<' - this makes the pattern faster.

Set the replace text to:

```
$0\r\n
```

Then, simply check the '*Extract matches*' option of the search/replace filter.

Finally, in the **Output Filter**, use the '*Single File Output*' to your destination filename.

Comment: Very constructive answer! Welcome to StackOverflow.